# How to determine the eigenvalues for this matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, stability-in-odes

Take a look at this matrix (Jacobian matrix):

$$
A = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \Big\vert_{x=x_{e_1}} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\dfrac{2\mu g}{(1+\mu y_0)} & -\dfrac{k}{m} & -\dfrac{\lambda\mu\sqrt{\dfrac{2gm}{\lambda\mu}}}{m(1+\mu y_0)}\\
0 & \mu \sqrt{\dfrac{2gm}{\lambda\mu}} & 
-\dfrac{R(\mu y_0 + 1)}{\lambda}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Assume all parameters are positive. I can replace it with 
$$
A = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \Big\vert_{x=x_{e_1}} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
a & -b & -c\\
0 & d & -e
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a,b,c,d,e>0$. Eigenvalues are determined via the characteristic equation $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. Matlab provides me with this values

[image]

Is there an alternative to check if the eigenvalues are positive, negative or at least one of them are zero without going through a tedious calculation? I don't care about the actual numerical values. This has something to do with the stability of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum of the eigenvalues should be equal to the trace of the matric (sum of diagonal elements). The product of eigenvalues should be equal to the determinant of the matrix.